# Which are the steps that a developer follows to develop a DApp?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development

I would like to know if based on your experience, the following **steps** are correct in order a **developer to develop a DApp from the start to the end.**

**Steps:**

1. Create an Externally Owned Account (EOA)
2. Receive the account address and the private key
3. Fund account with real or test Ether
4. Write Smart Contract
5. Complile Smart Contract
6. Deploy Smart Contract's bytecode
7. Approve transaction (sign transaction with private key)
8. Smart contract's address on Ethereum received
9. Setup DApp UI (e.g., HTML, CSS, JS, etc.)
10. Plug Web3.js library
11. Include Application Binary Interface (ABI)
12. Establish interaction with blockchain (for example check if an address is a valid Ethereum address)
13. Establish interaction with the smart contract (for example call a function of the smart contract)
14. **DAapp is configured and the process ends**

**Please, any steps and ideas are welcomed :) I need your experience**

Answer (score 0):

These steps are incorrect.

Usually the actual development happens using unit tests, integration tests and Ganache, no real Ethereum accounts involved.

For more information about professional Ethereum development frameworks, check e.g. [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, in case the developer wants to make a DApp live in the Ethereum mainnet, are the aforementioned steps correct?

Comment: No, because you do not do development on mainnet.

Comment: That's an opinion. It is a bad practice to do development on mainnet because you have to pay real fees and you can lose real assets, but you CAN do it.

Comment: But I guess that the aforementioned process steps can be performed on testnet, playing around with test Ether. Right?

Comment: But to Mikko's point, you should add steps that involve deploying and testing your Dapp on a testnet or on a local test node such as Ganache.

Comment: So, maybe is better if I write "first developer does all the aforementioned steps on the Ethereum testnet and once everything is successful, the developer can make the DApp work live on mainnet". So the point will be first testing on testnnet and then make it available on mainnet

Comment: Yes the steps could be performed on a testnet. But on a serious Dapp development, you would also use unit tests even before deploying on a testnet (using truffle and ganache, for instance). Unit tests are kind of automatic tests that are performed locally on your Dapp to make sure that it works as intended.

Comment: to be honest the reason that I ask these are for writing a paper and not for real development. So, I want to render the high-level process that a developer follows in order to develop and make a DApp live on Ethereum mainnet. So, if you think that from high-level perspective, something is missing, it would be helpful if you could mention it.